# SSIS - 2008 - Use a single config table for multiple copies of the same package

Tags: configuration, ssis

I am somewhat new to SSIS.

I have to deliver a 'generic' SSIS package, that the client will make multiple copies of, deploy and schedule each copy for different source databases.  I have a single SSIS Configuration table in a separate common database.  I would like to use this single configuration table  for all connections.  However the challenge is with the configuration filter.  When client makes a copy of my package, it will have the same configuration filter just like others.  I would like to give an option to the client to change the configuration filter before deploying, because for this new copy, the source database can be different.  I do not find an option to control this.

Is there a way to change the configuration filter from outside the package (without editing the executable .dtsx file)?  Or is there a better approach that I can follow?  I do not prefer XML configuration files, the primary reason being my packages are deployed onto SQL server.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.
-Shahul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your preferred solution does not align well with the way that SSIS package configurations are typically used. See Jamie Thomson's answer to [a similar question on the MSDN forums](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlintegrationservices/thread/67d5aa85-20cf-4392-9131-f1d5f8652e5b/).

Comment: Yeah.  That was one of my wild thoughts while trying to find a graceful solution.  I went ahead with XML configuration file for the source database connections (that will different for each source)  and config table for the common connections.  This should be manageable by the client, I hope.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a package with the same requirements for my company. It loads data from different sources and loads them into different destinations based on individual configurations for the instances. It is used as an internal ETL.

We have adapters that connect to different sources and pass data to a common staging table in XML format and the IETL Package loads this data into different tables depending on a number of different settings etc.

i.e. Multiple SSIS package instances can be executed with different configurations. You are on the right track. It can be achieved using SQL Server to hold configurations and XML Config file to hold the database info that has this configurations. When an instance of the package executes it will load the default values configured with the package, but needs to update all variables to reflect the purpose of the new instance.

I have created a Windows app to configure these instances and they settings in the database to make it really easy for the client or consultant to configure them without actually opening the package.